# htmx: Endless scrolling via "revealed" does not work

Tags: javascript, html, infinite-scroll, htmx

I want to use htmx [hx-trigger="revealed"](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/) to implement endless scrolling.

I send this html to the browser. In this case Note-20 should load the next note (Note-19):

```
    <h1 class="">Note-20</h1>
    <p class="">foo</p>
    <div hx-get="/note/19/" hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="outerHTML" class=""></div>
```

The URL `/note/19/` returns roughly the same HTML: it contains the data of Note-19 and at the end it tells the browser to load Note-18 on "revealed".

This works for the first notes. But then it stops.

What could be the reason?

**Update**

I create a simple demo application to show how you could use htmx with Django: [django-htmx-fun](https://github.com/guettli/django-htmx-fun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: In above code the `<div>` which triggers the loading via `hx-get` is empty.

If I add some content (for example "..."), then it works.

I guess my browser (Chrome) does not render the empty `<div>` and thus the revealed event is not triggered.

With a non-empty `<div>` it works.